# Java: divide number into equals parts or approximate to each other

Tags: java, android, numbers, integer

I have a numer = 20. And I want to divide this number into N equals parts or approximate to each other. N maybe from 1 to 20.

I write this code:

```
ArrayList<Integer> c = new ArrayList<>();
int num = 20;
int count = N; //where N some number (from 1 to 20)
int val = (int) Math.floor(num / count);

for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    c.add(val);
}
c.set(0, c.get(0) + num - sum(c));
```

It works fine, for example, when count = N = 3. I get: 8, 6, 6 (8+6+6=20). But if count = N = 12 I get next result: 9, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 (sum = 20). I want that result will be next: 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1 (sum = 20). Is that possible?

Answer (score 11):

You calculate the size of the *next* part, then reduce the values and repeat:

```
private static int[] splitIntoParts(int whole, int parts) {
    int[] arr = new int[parts];
    int remain = whole;
    int partsLeft = parts;
    for (int i = 0; partsLeft > 0; i++) {
        int size = (remain + partsLeft - 1) / partsLeft; // rounded up, aka ceiling
        arr[i] = size;
        remain -= size;
        partsLeft--;
    }
    return arr;
}
```

If you want, the method can be squeezed, though leaving it as above is better because it treats the parameters as immutable and clarifies the logic:

```
private static int[] splitIntoParts(int whole, int parts) {
    int[] arr = new int[parts];
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        whole -= arr[i] = (whole + parts - i - 1) / (parts - i);
    return arr;
}
```

*Test*

```
for (int parts = 0; parts <= 25; parts++)
    System.out.println(parts + ": " + Arrays.toString(splitIntoParts(20, parts)));
```

*Output*

```
0: []
1: [20]
2: [10, 10]
3: [7, 7, 6]
4: [5, 5, 5, 5]
5: [4, 4, 4, 4, 4]
6: [4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3]
7: [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2]
8: [3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2]
9: [3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
10: [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
11: [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1]
12: [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1]
13: [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
14: [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
15: [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
16: [2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
17: [2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
18: [2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
19: [2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
20: [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
21: [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]
22: [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]
23: [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
24: [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
25: [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Notice that `0` returns empty array. Add `if` statement if it should fail. Negative values will fail with `NegativeArraySizeException`. As you can see, too many parts will simple return parts of `0` size. Again, add `if` statement if that should fail

Answer (score 2):

Here you go

```
int x = 20;
int n = 12;
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
int f = x / n;
int r = x % n;
for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if(i <= n - r) list.add(f);
    else list.add(f + 1)
}
```

Comment: Thank you! But we must some correct code, because when n=2, there is result = 10, not 10,10.

Comment: @BinoyBabu I think you should switch in your code list.add(f+1) and list.add(f), because in case x = 8 and n=3 it will produce wrong result (it will be: [2, 2, 3] instead of expected: [3,3,2])

Answer (score 1):

I have an easy solution (though not the best) -

```
int[] parts = new int[count];

int j = 0;
for (int i=1; i<=num; i++) {
    parts[j] += 1;
    j++;
    if (j == count) {
        j = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't have to initialize the array to `0`, that's already done by the JVM.

Answer (score 1):

I modified your code a little. See if this works.

```
ArrayList<Integer> c = new ArrayList<>();
int num = 20;
int count = 12; //where N some number (from 1 to 20)
int val = (int) Math.floor(num / count);
int sum = 0;
int max = val;
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    c.add(val);
    sum+=c.get(i);
}

int temp = c.get(0) + num - sum;
int i=1;
while (temp > max) {
    if (i>=c.size())
        i = 1;
    temp-=1;
    c.set(i, c.get(i) + 1);
    if (max < c.get(i))
        max = c.get(i);
    i++;
}
c.set(0, temp);
System.out.println(c);
```

Comment: Very convoluted and inefficient code. Example: In the first loop, `c.get(i)` will always retrieve the value that was just added, so it's equal to `val`, except you get the cost of an array lookup and the unboxing of the `Integer`. Changing it to `sum+=val` will highlight the fact that `val` never changes, so the code is unnecessary if you simply initialize sum as `int sum = val * count`.